# Which Loss function is correct for binary mapping?

Tags: neural-network, loss-function, binary

I have built a 3 layer neural network to perform a binary mapping (2016 inputs, 288 outputs.) I am getting decent results with mean square error and stochastic gradient decent. My question is: Is there a more appropriate loss function for regression when the output is binary?

Comment: Hmm, for binary output it is more convenient to have sigmoid (softmax is not appropriate in this case, I guess) output and cross-entropy loss function.

Comment: What is meant by binary? Are you saying two outputs always or what? Share the output format as well.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use **binary cross-entropy loss**. In case you are using Keras, this has been [already implemented as a standard loss function](https://keras.io/losses/) for binary outputs.